# Java library that converts coffeescript to javascript or compiled java executable?

Tags: java, coffeescript

I would like to embed javascript into a java application but given coffeescript cleans up some of the superfluous syntax of javascript it would be great to support execution of coffee script in a java environment. I couldnt find any links and am asking here just incase someone knows of a translator or compiler.

Comment: You use CoffeeScript to compile to JavaScript...

Comment: I wish to keep everything *all* java, which is the origin of my request.

Comment: You can run the coffescript translator under Rhino and then run the output of that in Rhino.  Does that not qualify as an "all java" solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I understand you right, [JCoffeescript](https://github.com/yeungda/jcoffeescript) would fit what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

The wro4j project (which bundles a lot of HTML/JS/CSS processing steps for a Java toolchain, including Maven plugin) [also has CoffeeScript support](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/CoffeeScriptSuport).